# Error in mail.Bcc.Add() ASP .Net c#

Tags: asp.net, email, bcc

what I'm trying to achieve in my code below is to send an email for each email address that can be found in my database. My problem is when I click my send button an errors says that "`The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.`" on the `mail.Bcc.Add(MyVar.Text)` line.

```
private void sendmail()
    {
        Label MyVar = new Label();
        foreach (DataRowView UserEmail in SelectUserProfile.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty))
        {
            MyVar.Text = "";
            MyVar.Text += UserEmail["EMAIL"].ToString() + "; ";
        }

        //This line takes the last ; off of the end of the string of email addresses
        MyVar.Text += MyVar.Text.Substring(0, (MyVar.Text.Length - 2));

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.Bcc.Add(MyVar.Text);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("syntaxbugerror@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "New Member Application";
        mail.Body = "Good day, in this e-mail you can find a word document attached in which it contains new membership application details.";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypassword");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
```

Ernie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you buliding a string of the BCC email addresses?

The `Bcc` is a collection, so just treat it as such. I'm not really sure what you're doing with the label or why, so just ignoring that for now, something like this should work

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

foreach (DataRowView UserEmail in SelectUserProfile.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty))
{
   MyVar.Text = "";
   MyVar.Text += UserEmail["EMAIL"].ToString() + "; ";

   try
   {
       mail.Bcc.Add(UserEmail["EMAIL"].ToString());
   }
   catch(FormatException fe)
   {
      // Do something with the invalid email address error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic flow doesn't make sense.  You're parsing together emails and then attempting to unparse your email addresses through some flawed logic.  Instead, create your mail message and *then* loop through your email addresses, adding each to the BCC.

```
// Create Message (...)
foreach(...)
{
   mail.Bcc.Add(UserEmail["EMAIL"].ToString()); 
}
// Finalize and send (...)
```